# Schema.org structure in home page: markup many links to other inner pages?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have a question regarding using Schema.org: Let’s assume I have a home page, so I use the `WebSite` type.

But I have in the home page many links to articles and other inner pages, should I mark each one of them, because I have around 40 different types of links in my main page?

For example:
The main element is `WebSite` (home page), inside the home page I have list of inner pages, articles links (around 40 elements).
Is that of kind of marking is valid? Like marking a lot of elements in one page?

It is the same in other categories pages and so on.

I have never tried that and I’m not sure how to test it.

Here are two parts of my `WebPage`:

```html
<div class="related-posts">
          <div class="related-post col-sm-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <div class="small-thumb"><img itemprop="image" src="images/horse-thumb.jpg" alt="" width="58" height="43" /></div>
            <div class="latest-articles-content"> <a itemprop="url" href=""><h3 itemprop="name">פחוסי האף מה קרה...</h3></a>
              <div class="date"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-05-24">24 מאי 2014</time></div>
              <a class="comments-counter" href=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <span itemprop="commentCount">0</span></a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="related-post col-sm-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <div class="small-thumb"><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog-care.png" alt="" width="58" height="43" /></div>
            <div class="latest-articles-content"> <a itemprop="url" href=""><h3 itemprop="name">פחוסי האף מה קרה...</h3></a>
              <div class="date"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-05-24">24 מאי 2014</time></div>
              <a class="comments-counter" href=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <span itemprop="commentCount">0</span></a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="related-post col-sm-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <div class="small-thumb"><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog-2.jpg" alt="" width="58" height="43" /></div>
            <div class="latest-articles-content"> <a itemprop="url" href=""><h3 itemprop="name">פחוסי האף מה קרה...</h3></a>
              <div class="date"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-05-24">24 מאי 2014</time></div>
              <a class="comments-counter" href=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <span itemprop="commentCount">0</span></a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="related-post col-sm-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <div class="small-thumb"><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog-1.jpg" alt="" width="58" height="43" /></div>
            <div class="latest-articles-content"> <a itemprop="url" href=""><h3 itemprop="name">פחוסי האף מה קרה...</h3></a>
              <div class="date"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-05-24">24 מאי 2014</time></div>
              <a class="comments-counter" href=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <span itemprop="commentCount">0</span></a> </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
```

```html
    <ul>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog1.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">פאג</span></a></li>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog2.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">לברדור רטריבר</span></a></li>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog3.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">לברדור רטריבר</span></a></li>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog4.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">קבלייר קינג צארלס ספניאל</span></a></li>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog5.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">קייסהאונד</span></a></li>
                      <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><a itemprop="url" href=""><img itemprop="image" src="images/dog6.jpg" alt="Breed-name" /><span itemprop="name" class="gallery-caption">בול טרייר</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: 1. How would you "mark each" of the links? Please include some sample code in your question. 2. Asking about what Google would (not) like to see is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, so maybe you want to rephrase your question. We can help you if you have questions about using Schema.org (i.e., if you are using it correctly, or how it should be used according to Schema.org’s documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i will try to attach examples soon.

Comment: (You had some missing `>` in your second code example. I fixed them because I guess they were merely copy-paste errors.)

Answer (score 0):

> But I have in the home page many links to articles and other inner pages, should I mark each one of them, because I have around 40 different types of links in my main page?

You may do this, yes. (There is no "should", as Schema.org doesn’t define any requirements about what should or should not be marked up.)

> Is that of kind of marking is valid? Like marking a lot of elements in one page?

Yes, totally. You may markup everything that you want. There is no restriction to mark up, say, only the main content of a document. Generally you can say: the more data, the better -- that is, if you use only appropriate types and properties.

Currently, your `Article`/`WebPage` items don’t seem to be related to their parent item in any way.

So ideally you would use an appropriate property, if there exists one.  Maybe [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart), [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink), and [`significantLink`](http://schema.org/significantLink), e.g.:

- `WebSite` `hasPart` `WebPage`
- `WebPage` `relatedLink` `WebPage`
- `WebPage` `significantLink` `WebPage`